# Use of & operator in C++ Range Based Loop ..Confusing

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
char SArray[6]={'a','b','c','d','e','\0'};
for(char n: SArray) {
  n = 'R';
}
for (int i =0;i<7;i++) {
  cout << "Slot " << i << ":" << SArray[i] << endl;
}
```

```
Slot 0:a
Slot 1:b
Slot 2:c
Slot 3:d
Slot 4:e
Slot 5:
Slot 6:R
```

If loop is written this way for(char n: SArray), C++ puts 'R' After the array, to the next address(i checked addresses too)

If we declare n reference

for(char &n: SArray)

then its all good

```
Slot 0:R
Slot 1:R
Slot 2:R
Slot 3:R
Slot 4:R
Slot 5:R
Slot 6:╖
```

What does this expression do exactly?  **for(char n: SArray)**
And here, **for(char &n: SArray)**, &n, reference for what? i thought references can be created only to existing variables

Thank you!

Comment: a big flaw is you're assuming that "slot 6" is valid, its not. the array only has 6 elements but you're trying to print 7. that last "slot" being printed is not part of the array and accessing it as such is undefined behavior, which is probably causing most of your confusion

Comment: @kmdreko like kmdreko has commented, slot 6 does not exist, and I was surprised you actually print `R`out of it. Beside that, range based for loop works similar to a function. `for(char n: SArray)` was passed by value, and `for(char &n: SArray)` was passed by reference.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep could you please elaborate how it is similar to function?, yes i printed slot 6, was just playing, and accidently found 'R' there, or any other character which is assigned to "n".

Comment: @DmitriyBurtsev sorry if that had introduced more confusion to you. What I mean is that think of you have two functions, `void doA(int a)` and `void doB(int& b)`. When you called function A, you are only taking the value of `a`, and no matter what you do in that function, nothing actually happens to `a`. However, if you have called function B, you will actually be using `b` itself in that function, and if you have modified `b` in that function, then `b` itself will also be changed.

Comment: @DmitriyBurtsev similar things happened in the range based for loop. When you used `for(char n: SArray)`, you are not actually dealing with the datas from `SArray` anymore. Instead, you are only taking the value of each element of `SArray` and `char n = elementOfSArray`. So no matter what you do with `n`, nothing actually change on `SArray`. However, when you called `for(char &n: SArray)`, you are doing `char &n = elementOfSArray`. Now `n` is actually pointed to the elements. So changes done to `n` would also be done to your `SArray`.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep i got it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestions are:
First learn references `&` operator. But let me try to explain in a simple way than we can go more complex and explain the loop.

`&` represents reference and in simple terms references is different name for the same variable. For example

```
int a = 5;
int& b = a;
```

`b` is different name for `a`. Next example:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
int c = 5;

int& ref = a; // ref is different name for a
int& ref = b; // ref is now different name for b
int& ref = c; // ref is now different name for c
```

now lets put this analogy into your question:

```
char SArray[6]={'a','b','c','d','e','\0'};                                                         
for(char &n: SArray)
{
    n='R';
}
```

as loop goes on `char &n` refers to `SArray[i]` (is the name of `SArray[i]`)

where as

```
char SArray[6]={'a','b','c','d','e','\0'};                                                         
for(char n: SArray)
{
    n='R';
}
```

copies `SArray[i]` to new variable `n`

Comment: & represents reference and in simple terms references is different name for the same variable. For example  

int a = 5;  
int& b = a;  
this is clear, thank you.    But with, char &n refers to SArray[i] is not clear yet. Here &n becomes another name for SArray[0]....SArray[6]? or it refers to SArray[0] , changes its value to 'R', next loop it takes a name of SArray[1] etc..? @0x476f72616e

Comment: for(char n: SArray)
{
    n='R';
} copies SArray[i] to new variable n. if it copies to n, and then n gets 'R', thats why SArray stays unchanged right?@0x476f72616e

Comment: @DmitriyBurtsev that is exactly why SArray does not get changed. I think you got everything now

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `&` operator in a range based loop, you are telling the compiler you want to directly access the elements of the range. I.e. in your example, you directly modify each element in `SArray`.

When you do not use the `&`, you are asking the compiler to make a local copy of that element within the scope of the loop. In this case, when you write to `n` it does not update the actual element in the range, just the temporary variable, and so when the loop terminates the original array is unmodified.

So in general you use the `&` operator when your loop needs to update the range, and you leave out the `&` when you want the range to just be an input to the loop and not be updated.

You should also be aware of the syntax `for (const &n : SArray)` which gives read only direct access to an element in the range. A reason to use this syntax is when the elements of the range are large (e.g. a big struct) so you don't want to copy the data unnecessarily but you want to guard against an inadvertent write.